# Changing apparent scale of tile layers

Tags: qgis, openlayers, tiles, arcgis-pro

There's loads of web-based tile layers out there which are great in many ways, but one problem I'm having is making them look nice when exporting a map to print or as a jpeg.

The problem consistently seems to be that they display too much detail, which is fine for working with the maps on-screen, but for most publications I want to simplify the map and have everything nice and clear (particularly thinking of boundary and place-name layers). It seems to be that one way to achieve this would be to overrule the tile layer's Levels of Detail/Scale settings to get a lower Level of Detail despite the map being a large scale.

Is that possible (for a third-party, web-based tile layer)?

If not (or even if so) does anyone have an better ideas for achieving a similar effect?

I use both QGIS and ArcGIS Pro so a workaround in either would be OK.

Answer (score 2):

The only "solution" I've found (if you could call it that) in QGIS is to change the DPI of the Export Resolution under Export Settings in Layout Properties. Reducing the DPI will export a lower resolution layout but it will also change the zoom level of the basemap. To try to keep your data looking good you might want to try exporting to PDF first at the lower resolution and then converting the PDF to JPEG if need be.